# URL parameters determine load() url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a jQuery based web app and I want to use URL parameters to navigate around it.

I would like to display content based on the URL parameter, with the 'load()' function getting the main body of the web page from an external URL and replacing an element with it.

How would I create an if statement that use the following conditions...

- If there are no parameters in the url, then use `$("#toBeReplaced").load("home.txt");`
- If the parameter `page` is equal to `about`, then use `$("#toBeReplaced").load("about.txt");`
- If the parameter `page` is equal to `contact`, then use `$("#toBeReplaced").load("contact.txt");`

...to determine what page of the app to display.

Comment: There are many plugins/libraries out there to parse the url in js. Just grab a library you want and create a simple `if` statement. 1 minute of googling and 5 rows of code needed ... ;) like: https://github.com/websanova/js-url

Comment: @eisbehr I am pretty new to javascript and jQuery so I would quite like an example of some code I could use, so I could understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply load the url using `page` variable if it is `undefined` then load `home` otherwise load whatever is in `page` variable.

```
var page = location.search.substring(1).split('=')[1];
if (page == undefined)
  $("#toBeReplaced").load("home.txt");
else
  $("#toBeReplaced").load(page + ".txt");
```

Comment: how would I load the URL - sorry for asking such stupid questions, but I am new to this sort of thing so bare with me!

Comment: How your url look like ?

Comment: for example coding-kids.net/app?page=about

Comment: Keep in mind that this solution only works, if `page` is the **only** parameter in your url. `?page=about&foo=bar` or `?foo=bar&page=about` will not work. @DanielHarrin

Comment: @eisbehr ok that's fine. I am experiencing some issues with it - look at the source on this page - `http://ckdata.neocities.org/test.html`. I did some tests with `http://ckdata.neocities.org/test.html?page=google` and `http://ckdata.neocities.org/google.txt`. The contents of `google.txt` is not displaying in `test.html?page=google`. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because it is trying to load `google.txt`. You can do one thing that send `google.com` in page and load it. Then you need to change about to `about.txt` as well. So your urls will be like
`http://ckdata.neocities.org/test.html. I did some tests with http://ckdata.neocities.org/test.html?page=google.com and http://ckdata.neocities.org/google.txt. The contents of google.txt is not displaying in test.html?page=google

Comment: So how would I fix it?

Comment: I just used google as an example - I do not want to load it's homepage

Comment: I think I know why it is not working - I am using static web hosting. I have edited my question to allow for more answers.

Comment: @DanielHarrin can you send `google.com` as parameter ?

Comment: @Leopard, `google` was just used as a random keyword - It would be much better if we used home.txt and test?page=home. And it doesn't work either!

Comment: @Leopard it is working now - I didn't include `$(document).ready(function()` so it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different libraries or jQuery plugins to get url parameters in js. For this example I will use [`js-url`](https://github.com/websanova/js-url). Include the `url.min.js` file into your page. Then just use this to get the parameter `page` by `url("?page")` and create a simple `if`.

```
$(function() {    
    var page = url("?page");

    if( page === "about" ) {
        $("#toBeReplaced").load("about.txt");
    }

    else if( page === "contact" ) {
        $("#toBeReplaced").load("contact.txt");
    }

    else {
        $("#toBeReplaced").load("home.txt");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have downloaded the library as a zip, which file do I upload to the server? Is it `url.min.js`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As I wrote in my answer. @DanielHarrin